# Remove leading zeroes from a string

Tags: rust

What is the simplest way to remove all leading zeroes from a string?

Here is something I came up with:

```
let mut chars = original_str.chars();
let mut res = chars.as_str();
while chars.next() == Some('0') {
    res = chars.as_str();
}
```

Is there something better, in terms of brevity and/or performance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`str::trim_start_matches`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim_start_matches)

```rust
fn main() {
    assert_eq!("00foo1bar11".trim_start_matches('0'), "foo1bar11");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1b8dd9a4fa966d9cdca4289271b459c3)